# Как правильно прописать условие

Tags: php

Задача такая - в `ocstore` нужно сделать что бы заголовок раздела был `h1` если описание раздела пустое, но если описание раздела заполнено, то `h2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим у вас описание находится в некой переменной:

```
$des = "Здесь описание"; // некая переменная которой передается описание

if(strlen($des)==0){ // проверяем длину строки, если ноль то описание отсутствует и выводим просто заголовок 
    echo "<h1>Заголовок</h1>";
}
else { // в противном случае, если есть описание то выводим заголовок и описание
    echo "<h2>Заголовок</h2>";
    echo "<p>Описание</p>";
}
```

Comment: Топик стартер спрашивал про опенкарт, а ответ про то, как писать if и проверять длину строки. Основная часть вопроса (вангую) про то, как подтянуть описание раздела. Допишите, если знаете.